# Select-Object - count sub-properties

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell code:

```
Clear-Host

[xml]$Xml = @"
<Sequences>
    <Sequence>
        <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
        <SequencePackages>
            <Package>
                <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
                <PackageMeta>
                    <PackageSuccess>True</PackageSuccess>
                </PackageMeta>
            </Package>
            <Package>
                <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
                <PackageMeta>
                    <PackageSuccess>False</PackageSuccess>
                </PackageMeta>
            </Package>
        </SequencePackages>
    </Sequence>
</Sequences>
"@

$SummaryProperties = @(
    "SequenceName";
    @{ Name = "PackagesSuccess"; Expression = { <# ??? #> } };
    @{ Name = "PackagesFailed"; Expression = { <# ??? #> } };
    @{ Name = "PackageCount"; Expression = { <# ??? #> } };
)

$Xml.Sequences.Sequence | Select-Object $SummaryProperties | Format-Table

Remove-Variable -Name Xml -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

As you see, I have a XML with a `<Sequence>` node. 
Among other things, this node contains one or more `<Package>` nodes. 
A `<package>` has the information "PackageSuccess", which may be "True" or "False".

I want to create a table-summary. The table should look like this:

```
SequenceName PackagesSuccess    PackagesFailed     PackageCount      
------------ ---------------    --------------     ------------      
Sequence-A                 1                 1                2
```

I am not able to count the packages and at the moment I have no idea, on how to get this output. I kindly ask for your support.

Comment: Is `{ $_.SequencePackages.Package }` a copy-paste error? It's the same expression in all 3 calculated properties

Comment: That is the code I have till now. I did make an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `.Where()` extension method to filter the `Package` nodes on the nested success status:

```
# PackageSuccess
{ $_.SequencePackages.Package.Where({$_.PackageMeta.PackageSuccess -eq 'True'} ).Count }

# PackageFailure
{ $_.SequencePackages.Package.Where({$_.PackageMeta.PackageSuccess -eq 'False'} ).Count }

# PackageCount
{ $_.SequencePackages.Package.Count }
```

Comment: OMG, so easy. I was just trying with XPath ... :-) Thank you very much!